# One to Many: List parents if only it has children

Tags: grails

I have a one to many relationship I need to list all parents only if it has children.

I tried a criteria like this but it did not work

```
def c = One.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
  isNotNull "manies"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the newer `where` syntax:

```
One.findAll {
    manies.size() > 0    
}
```

This will create a query like:

```
from
    One this_ 
where
    ? < (
        select
            count(*) 
        from
            Many 
        where
            this_.id=one_id
    )
```

Comment: To be fair, I think you could've done it the way you tried before just replacing 'isNotNull' with `sizeGt 'manies', 0`. However, I tend to think the newer syntax is more readable.

Comment: i tried where solution and sizeGt solution both works well, thanks for the time Aaron, i hope it help someone else